# All elements with class should show when pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Objective**
To have the captions show for all images in this slider when the user clicks to "show descriptions."

**Current State**
Each slide has a "Show Description" which when pressed shows you the description for just that slide. The container remains open around it when you arrive to the next slide. But you once again have to press the "Show Description" to see the description for that image. And the description for the previous slides is now hidden.

**Background**
I have an image carousel that has captions [descriptions of the image] 
[image: default]

which should only show if the user clicks to see them. The user may also hide them.

[image: showing description]

But the issue is that when you slide to the next image, the caption is not shown (though the container is still revealed)

[image: error]

and you have to press to "Show/Hide Descriptions" again

---

**Code**
The demo is on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/wuDed)

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel-caption">           
  <a href="#" class="read-more">
    <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>&nbsp;Show/Hide Descriptions
  </a>
                     
  <div class="hide carousel-content">
    <p>Skull</p>
    <p>[text filler is here]</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide { display: none; }

.carousel-caption { background-color: #f3f3f3; }
.carousel-content { padding: 10px 0; }

.read-more {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var rm = $(".read-more");
  var hi = $('.hide');
  rm.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var now = $(this).siblings(".hide");
    now.slideToggle();
    hi.not(now).filter(':visible').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you, you want one single click to make all captions be open when the user clicks right/left? If so, change this:

```
var now = $(this).siblings(".hide");
```

into this:

```
var now = $(".hide");
```

Comment: yes, that answers my question as I originally phrased it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can slideup the description in the callback of the slider:

Check out the updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aoJFD

```
var hi;
window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
  startSlide: 0,
  speed: 300,
  auto: 600000,
  continuous: true,
  disableScroll: false,
  stopPropagation: false,
  callback: function(index, elem) {

    hi.slideUp();
  },
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
});


$(document).ready(function () {
  var rm = $(".read-more");
  hi = $('.hide');
  rm.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var now = $(this).siblings(".hide");
    now.slideToggle();
    hi.not(now).filter(':visible').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

A detailed explanation follows:

> But the issue is that when you slide to the next image, the caption is
>   not shown (though the container is still revealed)

The container is revealed because caption for previous slide is still visible but shifted horizontally. The caption for current slide is not visible because it is invisible by styling, as has not yet been made visible.

Comment: Oh wow, this was even better than I previously imagined. More practical to do it this way. Thank you so much.